# Move from xib to storyboard in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I have app that has single xib file and in this xib file I have created tableList ok that's fine it is working fine.

Here my main requirement is when I click tableList row I want to move "xib" file to my UIStroryBoard and for this I have searched lot in internet but I did not get any solutions.

Please help me with some code.

When I search in internet only I get how to move one xib to another xib like below code, but I want to move xib file to UIstrotyboard.

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Try DetailViewController * detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"]; to create object of class because code is different for both xib and storyboard. And set Identifier of your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that you can push to a `ViewController` on `Storyboard`

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your_storyboard_name" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController *detailVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Even, `self.storyboard` should help.

Comment: @Hemang If you are initialized this storyboard before, you can use `self.storyboard`. But if this `ViewController` belong to another storyboard, your `detailVC ` will be nill. For example, I have 5 storyboard files in my project. And I have to check it every time i call push method

Answer (score 0):

this is the same code but in swift

```
     let myStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "<the name of  new storyboard as in 
      Project Navigator >", bundle: nil) 
       // the View Controller on the Story board that you will navigate to it
    let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "< the string identifier of the view controller >")
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal // as example
    present(vc, animated: true)
```